# View rendered output of a gist?

Tags: git, github, gist

I'm sure I'm being dim, but is it possible to view the rendered output of a gist?

This is the gist I'm interested in: https://gist.github.com/844752/420cc52eb4910fe8fa2bec9e13daab18b6230503

Where can I see how it actually renders?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know gist doesn't provide an execution environment, but you could easily paste this in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net).

Comment: I just ended up running it locally... was easier than jsfiddle. But thanks for clarifying that gist doesn't render output.

Comment: you can try www.ideone.com

Answer (score 54):

[rawgit.com](//rawgit.com) provides this service. To use rawgit.com, simply replace the domain of the raw view of the gist or github file you want to view with rawgit.com. For example:

```
https://gist.githubusercontent.com/mbostock/844752/raw/index.html
```

to

```
https://rawgit.com/mbostock/844752/raw/index.html
```

or

```
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/caffinatedmonkey/Hello-World-PSP/master/main.cpp
```

to

```
https://rawgit.com/caffinatedmonkey/Hello-World-PSP/master/main.cpp
```

Comment: I'd rather not use a 3rd party service. They have an API -there's no reason we shouldn't be able to get the actual output from it. Oh well

Comment: @SeanKPS Rawgit uses Github's gist APIs to get data and render it as html.

Comment: @@0xcaff which property from the API results contains the data?

Comment: @SeanKPS You can get the contents of a gist by visiting the raw url (https://developer.github.com/v3/gists/#get-a-single-gist) (`files.[file_name].raw`). `rawgit` probably proxies the request to github, rewriting the response headers to add a  `Content-Type: text/html`.

Comment: @@0xcaff anyway to get the non-raw output?

Comment: _RawGit will soon shut down and is no longer serving new repos. Please visit https://rawgit.com for more details._

Answer (score 12):

## 2020 Update: RawGit is shutting down. Alternatives and tests:

To preview your gists as rendered HTML, use one of the services below:

- <s>rawgit.com</s> ([obsolete](https://rawgit.com/))
- [raw.githack.com](https://raw.githack.com/) (**WARNING**: injects JavaScript to your page!)
- [gitcdn.xyz](https://gitcdn.xyz/)
- [gistcdn.rawgit.org](https://gistcdn.rawgit.org/)
- [htmlpreview.github.io](https://htmlpreview.github.io/) (this is not a proxy, it loads your page via AJAX on the frontend)

All of those were tested with HTML gists on GitHub and are working as of July 2020.

### Tests

Examples using this gist:

- https://gist.github.com/rsp/977d142fd21bfd0f070a3e6b9758ac99#file-script-html

Check to see if it still works and how the URLs look like:

#### <s>rawgit.com</s> (doesn't work as of July 2020)

https://rawgit.com/rsp/dd2481a75c1668846a752e24099ce020/raw/233e4d9d5388fc087785ff2d6f63ce232302d255/test.html

#### gist.githack.com

https://gist.githack.com/rsp/dd2481a75c1668846a752e24099ce020/raw/233e4d9d5388fc087785ff2d6f63ce232302d255/test.html

**Warning:** It injects JavaScript to your page! See:

```sh
curl https://gist.githack.com/rsp/dd2481a75c1668846a752e24099ce020/raw/233e4d9d5388fc087785ff2d6f63ce232302d255/test.html
```

Output:

```
<!-- Valid HTML Test -->
<!doctype html>
<html lang=en>
<meta charset=utf-8> 
<title>Valid HTML Test</title>
<script>
alert('It works');
</script>
<script async src='/cdn-cgi/bm/cv/2172558837/api.js'></script><script type="text/javascript">(function(){window['__CF$cv$params']={r:'5b1aaf571d8bf2c0',m:'65442fcb36a12a3fd4d99294f0ae0a2c6c071945-1594556076-1800-AdUTDXjrrqS1ZqgeCevOb/vrvZSZaBf8uXiIHtYhab+Pu1AhAHEnvoPv7d6apyJwU+p7FNPWY8VQAjdSpjC5/5JRJKo5Og1S5Qod6jctf3ECBmhA7mctVQJOrzVBXkf2fZrHHOVjSD5cezyUp1zDZeSLAYtov29CfJKdbN7/gstPjgYcF/FbgiA5tm4WJ/ToqDwoSGljZwlHIrqr9EdLCecSgQO1D+ASFBtWOduqNIx9',s:[0x603d28608f,0x9fc0e2444b],}})();</script>
```

**The last two script tags are not mine!**
I noticed it because the HTML Validator is giving me warnings for a perfectly valid HTML (so it not only injects code, but an invalid one at that...)

#### gitcdn.xyz

https://gitcdn.xyz/cdn/rsp/dd2481a75c1668846a752e24099ce020/raw/233e4d9d5388fc087785ff2d6f63ce232302d255/test.html

Doesn't seem to change the HTML:

```sh
curl -v https://gitcdn.xyz/cdn/rsp/dd2481a75c1668846a752e24099ce020/raw/233e4d9d5388fc087785ff2d6f63ce232302d255/test.html
```

#### gistcdn.rawgit.org

https://gistcdn.rawgit.org/rsp/dd2481a75c1668846a752e24099ce020/233e4d9d5388fc087785ff2d6f63ce232302d255/test.html

**Note:** the URL doesn't contain `/raw/` like all the others so it's easy to misspell the URL if you construct it manually.

#### htmlpreview.github.io

https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://gist.githubusercontent.com/rsp/dd2481a75c1668846a752e24099ce020/raw/233e4d9d5388fc087785ff2d6f63ce232302d255/test.html

## Warning:

They seem to differ in regards to:

- some are proxy, some work with AJAX on the frontend
- changing the actual HTML like injecting scripts, see my warnings above

### File integrity

I wrote this script to check the SHA1 sums of the served HTML:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
for i in \
'https://gist.githubusercontent.com/rsp/dd2481a75c1668846a752e24099ce020/raw/233e4d9d5388fc087785ff2d6f63ce232302d255/test.html' \
'https://gist.githack.com/rsp/dd2481a75c1668846a752e24099ce020/raw/233e4d9d5388fc087785ff2d6f63ce232302d255/test.html' \
'https://gitcdn.xyz/cdn/rsp/dd2481a75c1668846a752e24099ce020/raw/233e4d9d5388fc087785ff2d6f63ce232302d255/test.html' \
'https://gistcdn.rawgit.org/rsp/dd2481a75c1668846a752e24099ce020/233e4d9d5388fc087785ff2d6f63ce232302d255/test.html' \
'https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://gist.githubusercontent.com/rsp/dd2481a75c1668846a752e24099ce020/raw/233e4d9d5388fc087785ff2d6f63ce232302d255/test.html' \
;do
n=`echo $i | sed 's|^[a-z:]*//||; s|/.*||'`
s=`curl -s $i | shasum`
echo $s $n
done
```

Feel free to use it to test the integrity of your own gists if needed.
Remember that even if one of the proxies doesn't inject anything or mess with your code **right now**, it doesn't mean that it will never do it.

My result was:

```
7a785588d5806469a7a9256968f82257accd7183 - gist.githubusercontent.com
809819224097b5f116b63fd6019cb490005d1ff8 - gist.githack.com
7a785588d5806469a7a9256968f82257accd7183 - gitcdn.xyz
7a785588d5806469a7a9256968f82257accd7183 - gistcdn.gistcdn.rawgit.org
5069f27b01308f3cf71c9d7f3a5c924e3a91b243 - htmlpreview.github.io
```

The first one is the original, so it seems that:

- gitcdn.xyz and rawgit.org serve the original file
- githack.com **injects scripts into your page!** (a git **hack** indeed...)
- htmlpreview.github.io works on the frontend so serves a different page that loads and displays your gist using a logic on the frontend (I wonder if it would work for relative links and images - I'll have to test it later).

#### Note on htmlpreview.github.io

Interestingly enough, it works using another service, a JSONP proxy [jsonp.afeld.me](https://jsonp.afeld.me/) and loads your gist not directly from GitHub but as:
https://jsonp.afeld.me/?url=https://gist.githubusercontent.com/rsp/dd2481a75c1668846a752e24099ce020/raw/233e4d9d5388fc087785ff2d6f63ce232302d255/test.html

### Other ideas

I just got an idea to see if gh-pages can be somehow made to work with gists (because gists can be checkout as repos). I'll test it and write an update. Update: I wasn't able to make it work. Nor could I deploy from a gist to Netlify.

Comment: htmlpreview.github.io worked well for me.

Answer (score 9):

I'm under the impression the way to render a gist has recently changed. Here is the solution I have found :

- go to http://rawgit.com/, paste the adress of your gist and get the adress to the raw html code - or click on the **raw** button in Github
- prepend to the URL: `http://htmlpreview.github.io/?`

#### Example

- link to a gist: https://gist.github.com/stla/9007180
- link generated by rawgit.com: https://rawgit.com/stla/9007180/raw/ or link by pressing the **raw** button: https://gist.githubusercontent.com/stla/9007180/raw/
- link to the rendered version: http://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://rawgit.com/stla/9007180/raw/ or http://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://gist.githubusercontent.com/stla/9007180/raw/

Comment: "RawGit is shutting down"

Comment: @Benny but htmlpreview still works with both https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://gist.githubusercontent.com/jpluimers/9a50d0ba14fe975906ea8788a352e269/raw/cde35d4a6b55050206d70daa597d04590585a419/PostScriptBooks.html and https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://gist.githubusercontent.com/jpluimers/9a50d0ba14fe975906ea8788a352e269/raw/

Answer (score 8):

Mike Bostock made a cool application to render Gists: http://bl.ocks.org/844752/420cc52eb4910fe8fa2bec9e13daab18b6230503

Still, I'm interested how this is done technically. GitHub has a cool api through which you can get gist data as JSON: https://api.github.com/gists/844752/420cc52eb4910fe8fa2bec9e13daab18b6230503 It includes the files and their raw contents. I don't know how to render it dynamically as if they were actual files on a filesystem.

Answer (score 8):

RawGithub.com will let you render anything on Github, including gists.  Two examples:

- https://gist.github.com/mbostock/4341574, and the [rendered version](https://rawgithub.com/mbostock/4341574/raw/3c483a24da81d8e4e5870113a3eb7036e8ea0190/index.html)
- https://gist.github.com/hemulin/4148842, and the [rendered version](https://rawgithub.com/hemulin/4148842/raw/7f5408ad6d0d61dfd7aa89071415e28c63b7ffd0/index.html)

Comment: Update: RawGit.com is closing down

"RawGit is now in a sunset phase and will soon shut down. It's been a fun five years, but all things must end."

Answer (score 0):

Gist renders output (currently after updating gist, not live preview).

This works only with proper file extension.

For example, if your file is formatted as MediaWiki, you have to edit the file name as `somefile.mediawiki`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it right in GitHub. I simply use the comment section as it already has its own 'Preview' option, and of course "Styling with Markdown is supported".

Answer (score 0):

For people visiting in 2022, the solution that worked for me is https://bl.ocks.org/-/about

> Bl.ocks (pronounced “Blocks”) is a simple viewer for sharing code examples hosted on GitHub Gist. For example, if your Gist URL is:
>
> https://gist.github.com/mbostock/1353700
>
> Replace “gist.github.com” with “bl.ocks.org” in the URL to view it:
>
> https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1353700
>
> The main source for your example is in index.html. This file can contain relative links to other files in your Gist, such as images, scripts or stylesheets. And of course you can use absolute links, such as CDN-hosted D3, jQuery or Leaflet. To explain your example, add a README.md written in Markdown. (You can omit the index.html if you just want to write, too.)